# Visual Studio - show all calls to a function in source code level

Tags: visual-studio, function-calls

I am wondering if there is any way to list all the calls to a function in source code, so that I could see the dependencies if I modify that function.

One method I use is to search the function name in the "Entire Solution" but I am looking for a better way.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Right-click on the call and select "Find All References".

Answer (score 12):

A brute force method is to change the name of the function and recompile and look at the errors. Sometimes I have trouble with the Find References functionality in VS.

Comment: This is the crudest, grungiest tip I've ever heard! But it speaks to blood lost trying any other way. I love it!

Comment: I think I got this tip from Martin Fowlers Refactoring book, if you were curious :)

Answer (score 8):

On method declaration:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Use [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/). It comes with a VS add-in that allows you to do CQL queries on the fly. See [this screenshot](http://www.ndepend.com/Res/NDependBig09.PNG).

Comment: Of course this only works for .NET code and not unmanaged C++ code

Comment: www.cppdepend.com - yup, virtually identical tool for C++